# Changing OCaml's allocation model when creating new values and accessing data

Tags: database, memory-management, ocaml

Is it possible to change the OCaml values allocation model, so that everything is stored in secondary memory instead of using primary memory and the program's heap? The use case scenario is dealing with big data and keeping all the already existing code as it is (backward compatibility and reuse), so that when I have to write an OCaml function I don't have to worry on the amount of data I'm dealing with (e.g. streamed from an external source, without loading all the data in primary memory), and that any returned value will be automatically stored in secondary memory, preferebly into a key/value store or in a relational database.

Comment: Is just some specific data that you want to allocate on secondary memory, or the whole heap ?

Comment: Good question. Well, the data I would like to persist and update is only one single function argument per function, representing a stream/list of a discriminated union type. Such stream/list is going to be constantly/recursively updated as in a (transitive) closure/fixpoint evaluation. Some light data can be loaded in primary data and stay there for the whole execution time.

Comment: E.g., in primary memory I have a set of FOL formulae and in secondary memory I keep the grounded FOL relations that will guide me into providing the finite model.

Comment: have you considered using things like LMDB  https://symas.com/lmdb/ ?
It seems there are multiple ocaml bindings :
 https://github.com/vbmithr/ocaml-lmdb
 https://github.com/Drup/ocaml-lmdb

Comment: https://github.com/Drup/ocaml-lmdb  only supports string key and values, and both of them would generally require to use marshalling and unmarshalling. Do you know any technique that is opaque to how the data is actually stored, so that I can also use values that are instance of discriminated union types, or maybe it's easier to put the whole heap in secondary memory?

Comment: If you are thinking of the whole heap then just add swap. Seems though like you would want persistence across runs and that means either doing filesystem or database access. Something that won't be totally transparent.

Comment: The only library I was able to find for the swap was "ancient", but it seems an old project. Can you suggest a more recent library that is also supported by OPAM?

So, I suppose that there is no library yet that does that for persistency, like OR Mapping for object oriented languages.